# how To Return Function's returned value using ternary Operator in python

Tags: python-3.x

e.g

Here Function `heapifyUp` is getting called twice
(I Need a single call).

```
return self.heapifyUp(parentIndex) if self.heapifyUp(parentIndex) != -1 else realIndex
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's called twice because
you call it twice... :-)

To call it once, assign the result to a variable:

```
res = self.heapifyUp(parentIndex)
return res if res != -1 else realIndex
```

(BTW, you don't need the `;` at the end)

Comment: actually i am calling heapifyUp function in recursion. so i have to break somewhere else if will go on calling itself.